# standby widget with dojo datagrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I m trying to use a standby widget that will keep loading, till the dojo datagrid is loaded.
I m trying this. But, standby widget doesn't appear. It just waits, and loads the data.

```
        require([
        "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
        "dojo/store/Memory",
        "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
        "dojo/request",
        "dojox/widget/Standby",
        "dijit/form/Button",
        "dojo/domReady!",
        ],
        function (DataGrid, Memory, ObjectStore, request, Standby, Button) {
            var standby = new Standby({ target: "grid" });
            document.body.appendChild(standby.domNode);
            standby.startup();
            standby.show();
            var grid, dataStore;
            request.get("MyFile.aspx", {
                handleAs: "json"
            }).then(function (data) {
                dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: new Memory({ data: data }) });
                grid = dijit.byId("grid");
                grid.setStore(dataStore, { id: "*" }, {});                    
                var struct = [
                    { name: "Field1", field: "Name", width: "50%" },
                    { name: "Field2", field: "Name2", width: "50%" }, ];
                grid.setStructure(struct);
                grid.startup();
                standby.hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's just a problem in the order of the calls. You have to first initialize your grid, then initialize the standby, then fetch the data and set it in the grid and then hide the standby. In your case:

```
    require([
        "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
        "dojo/store/Memory",
        "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
        "dojo/request",
        "dojox/widget/Standby",
        "dijit/form/Button",
        "dojo/domReady!",
        ],
        function (DataGrid, Memory, ObjectStore, request, Standby, Button) {
            //Create the grid
            var grid = new DataGrid({
                query: { id : '*' },
                structure : [
                    { name: "Field1", field: "Name", width: "50%" },
                    { name: "Field2", field: "Name2", width: "50%" }
                ]
            }, 'grid');
            grid.startup();

            //Create the stand by
            var standby = new Standby({ target: "grid" });
            document.body.appendChild(standby.domNode);
            standby.startup();
            standby.show();

            //Fetch data
            var grid, dataStore;
            request.get("teste.php", {
                handleAs: "json"
            }).then(function (data) {
                var grid = dijit.byId('grid');

                //Create store and put in the grid
                dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: new Memory({ data: data }) });
                grid.setStore(dataStore, { id: "*" }, {});

                //Hide standby
                standby.hide();
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
   );
```